# Using random.choice in a loop

Tags: python, loops, random, module

I'm new to learning Python, currently learning Modules.
I'm stuck on this:

1. Randomly choose an element until you choose "yellow", incrementing flips each time
2. Print a message each time including how many flips have been executed and what the result was

```python
import random 

flips = 0
sides = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "blue"]

side = random.choice(sides) 

for side in sides:
    if side == "blue":
        print("you flipped a blue")
        flips += 1
    elif side =="yellow":
        print("you flipped a yellow!")
        flips += 1
        break
```

the output i got for this was:

you flipped a blue
you flipped a blue
you flipped a blue
you flipped a blue
you flipped a yellow!
5

I can see here that it's just iterating through my sides list till it gets to "yellow". How do I fix this to actually be random??

Comment: You are not using your random choice. After you make that choice, you are just doing an iterations through `sides`

Comment: Maybe you should, as you suggested in the title, use `random.choice` in the loop?

Comment: `side in sides` redefines `side`.  You are just looping through your list of sides

Comment: It's not clear from your description whether you are sampling colors with replacement or without. Without replacement is achieved by shuffling the list and iterating. With replacement means you make a random choice each time that is independent of your prior choices, so the luck of the draw can yield the same blue item multiple times before you land on the yellow. You get different answers depending on whether you have replacement or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `random.shuffle()` to random a list.

The code would be like this :

```
import random 

flips = 0
sides = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "blue"]

side = random.shuffle(sides) 

for side in sides:
    if side == "blue":
        print("you flipped a blue")
        flips += 1
    elif side =="yellow":
        print("you flipped a yellow!")
        flips += 1
        break
```

Comment: If you shuffle the list then there's no need to accumulate *flips* because the index of 'yellow' in the list (+1) gives you the flip count

Answer (score 0):

Your code right now assigns a random side to the variable `side`

```
side = random.choice(sides)
```

But after that in the for loop, you're reassigning the variable by iterating through `sides` list.

```
for side in sides: # here it gets reassigned
    if side == "blue":
        print("you flipped a blue")
        flips += 1
    elif side =="yellow":
        print("you flipped a yellow!")
        flips += 1
        break
```

What you're achieving is independent of the `sides` list. You can modify your code and using a while loop, as you want to break free of the loop only after a certain condition.

```
while True:
    side = random.choice(sides) # The side gets reassigned each time
    if side == "blue":
        print("you flipped a blue")
        flips += 1
    elif side =="yellow":
        print("you flipped a yellow!")
        flips += 1
        break
# rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with while loop you can use it in your current code. You want to choose random color until 'yellow' had been chosed. For this particular situation I suggest using while loop, because it iterates over until the certain condition is true. Here is updated code which satisfies the requirements you want using while loop.

```
    import random

    flips = 0
    sides = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "blue"]

    while True:
        side = random.choice(sides)
        flips += 1

        if side == "blue":
            print("You flipped a blue.")
        elif side == "yellow":
            print("You flipped a yellow!")
            break

    print("Total flips:", flips)
```

If you still considering use of for loop here is the code you can implement:

```
    import random

    flips = 0
    sides = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "blue"]

    random.shuffle(sides)  # Shuffle the sides list randomly

    for side in sides:
        flips += 1

        if side == "blue":
            print("You flipped a blue.")
        elif side == "yellow":
            print("You flipped a yellow!")
            break

    print("Total flips:", flips)
```

Comment: I wanted to use a While loop to begin with but wasn't sure how - thank you!

Comment: Your second code fragment may never report "You flipped a yellow!". Can you see why?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to indent side variable itself, Thaks.

Comment: @SunnatAmirov random.shuffle() returns None

Comment: @IzziTho Not at all !

Comment: @DarkKnight what about now ?